# uiscreen brightness beyond maximum value

Tags: objective-c, ios, brightness, uiscreen

I know it's possible to change the brightness of the iphone screen through code with

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```

but I wonder if it's possible to go beyond the maximum brightness level which is set in iPhone, and make the screen even brighter?

I'm thinking of an App which would use the screen as some sort of light source, but in the context I'm thinking of the maximum brightness isn't enough. (the iphone should be hooked up to a powersupply obviously otherwise the battery would be dead in an hour)

So, is this even possible (I think it's not, as max float is 1.0) and does apple accept apps which go beyond their own settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set the Brightness higher than 1.0. 
It will get clipped to 1.0.
You can easily find that out when you try setting it to a higher value and afterwards read it out like this:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:2.0];
NSLog(@"Brightness: %f",[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness);
```

it will print out: Brightness: 1.000000

Comment: Yes I thought so, and there is no other way right? Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way that apple would accept, cause there is a reason for the maxvalue like battery life and components getting too hot otherwise. But I bet there will be a way to get around it on deepest system levels if you google enough but I doubt you'll have a chance to get this into the App store then.

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing. The library documents are pretty unambiguous that the highest setting is 1.0 and anything beyond that gets clipped. It is also entirely reasonable that you do to want to burn in the display. 

My Galaxy S7 has a measured white below 100 nits but reviews say it can go over 850 nits when Automatic Brightness is turned On, in high ambient light. I suspect the Android limit is a safe limit, while the maker's Automatic Brightness can be tuned to the limits of the particular display.

Strap a powerful white LED to your light level sensor?